# RemoteApp Manager SSL certificate extend expiry date

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, remoteapp

I have setup an RDP RemoteApp Server for deploying a couple of programs.

The self-signed SSL certificate that I created only has a 6-month lifespan! Is it possible to extend this expiry date?

[image: Certificate Information]

Comment: Since it is self-signed, just create another certificate.  If that was the certificate that was automatically generated, then I think if you leave it alone, it will just auto-renew.